# What's a portable and lightweight comet server implementation?

Tags: comet

We're developing a web application in PHP and delivering it either on-premise or in the cloud. Cloud servers are Linux, whereas most on-premise customers are on Windows platforms.

For on-premise customers we are distributing an Apache/PHP stack and I would like to have push functionality in the system. Doing long polling in an Apache/mod_php setting might work for on-premise customers, but it's big no-no for scalability in the cloud.

I have been looking around at most Comet server implementations and it looks like they either:

- Are heavyweight and complex (CometD)
- Are single-platform (APE)
- Depend on a whole different platform (Orbited)
- Or don't look very maintained (nginx + http_push_module)

I would love to run into something like memcached for push: light, fast and cross platform, but I haven't been able to.

Suggestions, anyone? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am still in the early learning phase of Comet programming, but since you have yet to receive any answers I'll try to help by suggesting [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/) + [Socket.IO](http://socket.io/). To keep descriptions simple... Node.js is basically an event-driven, non-blocking web server and Socket.IO is a WebSocket emulator (and much more)... perfect for Comet development.

Also, if you are interested in using a third party hosted service, [Pusher](http://pusher.com/) seems to be pretty cool.